# Remove element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is DOM, there is a button to remove the parent here:

```
<i class="fa fa-times remove-product-compare" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

This is my DOM:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 pull-right comp-container" style="padding: 0;margin: 10px 0 10px 0;">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right compareProduct">
    <h3 style="text-align: right;">
product
    </h3>
    <i class="fa fa-times remove-product-compare" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <img src="images/photos/6.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="height: 250px;width: 100%" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right compareProduct">
    <h3 style="text-align: right;">
        product2
    </h3>
    <i class="fa fa-times remove-product-compare" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <img src="images/photos/2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="height: 250px;width: 100%" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right compareProduct">
    <h3 style="text-align: right;">
        product3
    </h3>
    <i class="fa fa-times remove-product-compare" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <img src="images/photos/3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="height: 250px;width: 100%" />
</div>
```

This Javascript code is supposed to hide the parent and works correctly:

```
$(".remove-product-compare").on("click",function (e) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

But this code is supposed to remove the parent from the DOM and doesn't work:

```
$(".remove-product-compare").on("click",function (e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/M6N24/103/

Comment: my code remove last item when i click on first item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The parent() method returns the direct parent element of the selected element.

```js
$(function() {
$(".remove-product-compare").click(function (e) {
       $(this).parent().remove();
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 pull-right comp-container" style="padding: 0;margin: 10px 0 10px 0;">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right compareProduct">
        <h3 style="text-align: right;">
product
        </h3>
        <i class="fa fa-times remove-product-compare" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <img src="images/photos/6.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="height: 250px;width: 100%" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right compareProduct">
    <h3 style="text-align: right;">
        product2
    </h3>
    <i class="fa fa-times remove-product-compare" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <img src="images/photos/2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="height: 250px;width: 100%" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right compareProduct">
    <h3 style="text-align: right;">
        product3
    </h3>
    <i class="fa fa-times remove-product-compare" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <img src="images/photos/3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" style="height: 250px;width: 100%" />
</div>
```

Comment: tanx,what problem was?

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.